# wc -m in unix adds one character

Tags: linux, wc

Counting a line with 4 characters with no new line character:

```
ACTG
```

`wc -m` gives me 5. With echo, I can fix this problem so

```
echo -n 'ACTG' | wc -m
```

But if `ACTG` is in a text file with no new line character, I get 5. Why is that so?

```
$ ls -l file

-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 5 Feb 11 15:27 file
$ hexdump -C file

00000000  41 42 43 44 0a                                    |ABCD.|
00000005
```

Comment: please see in the edits for the answer

Comment: I don't think we can mark duplicates across SE sites but here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66360/character-count-in-unix-wc-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hexdump has shown you, whatever editor you are using is adding a '\n' or 0x0A (new line) character at the end of the line when you save the file, even if you aren't writing one explicitly.

See: http://www.asciitable.com/